# How to set cookie in faraday

Tags: session, cookies, sinatra, faraday

I'm using Faraday as an HTTP client to test my HTTP service (based on Sinatra). It's very powerful for me, but I have a problem.

We track sessions on the Sinatra service, but I cannot set the cookie value with the Faraday client. This is the sample code:

```
# `response` is from the Sinatra service
cookie = response.headers['set-cookie']

# now, for the follow up request...
response = client.get '/api/profile' do |req|
  req.headers['Cookie'] = cookie
end
```

The server cannot find the session. Why?

Comment: Add `conn.response :logger` to your Faraday middleware as shown in the [README](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday). Then, please share your Sinatra and Faraday logs, preferably by linking to a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: I add the logger, but it does not wrong again. Maybe it is my falt in other places.I'm sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Set-Cookie` and `Cookie` headers are not the same, read the RFC to know how to interpret them. In short the `Set-Cookie` header also contains instructions for the client how to handle the data (domain, path, expiry, etc.) and gives an *update* to the existing cookie store. The `Cookie` header on the other hand provides the contents of the cookie store, but not the meta data.

You would need to obtain or implement some kind of cookie handler to insert into your Faraday middle-ware stack.

Comment: [faraday-cookie_jar](https://github.com/miyagawa/faraday-cookie_jar) seems to fill that space.